# Java/jetty does not respond to connections after a period of heavy load

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jetty

We are experiencing a very tricky problem with our java servlet, running under Jetty. It works perfectly well when the load is low to moderate, but when the load reaches a certain level it will cease responding to requests after about 10-20 minutes.

If we trace the main java process while connecting to it using curl, we can see that it sets up the connection, receives the request, parses it and does what it normally does (query a Solr server, perform some MySQL queries etc), but the result is never sent back to the client.

When it hangs, it will hang indefinitely. No amount of time will make it "snap out of it", BUT if we kill any random thread under the main java/jetty process, the number of threads goes down and it starts responding to requests again.

Here’s how it looks:

```
# curl http://localhost:8080/some-servlet-url

(Does not respond at this point)

# ps -efL | grep qserv | wc -l
243
# ps -efL | grep qserv | wc -l
243
# ps -efL | grep qserv | wc -l
243

(Number of threads remain seemingly constant)

# kill 29760   <--- random thread under the main java/jetty process
# ps -efL | grep qserv | wc -l
26

(Number of threads immediately decreases sharply)

# curl http://localhost:8080/some-servlet-url
... HTTP response ...

(Responds to connections again)
```

The server is an m2.2xlarge Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and Jetty 8.1.7.v20120910

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

We’ve tried several different java and Jetty versions. We’ve also tried using Tomcat instead of Jetty - same problem.

Profiling the app using YourKit shows no apparent thread locking or excessive CPU usage.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** We were able to get a stack trace of the hanging java process, and it looks like all the http threads are in this state:

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe518007800 nid=0x1fc5 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe57934f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000076ee9d230> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:810)
        - locked <0x000000076ee9d230> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:95)
        at net.acmecorp.active.QueryResultXMLFormatter.selectBestHitsAndRunDocumentCompletion(QueryResultXMLFormatter.java:362)
        at net.acmecorp.active.QueryResultXMLFormatter.queryResultToXMLRootElement(QueryResultXMLFormatter.java:167)
        at net.acmecorp.active.QueryPrepareAndExecuter.prepareParametersAndExecuteQuery_AndInvokeFormatter(QueryPrepareAndExecuter.java:239)
        at net.acmecorp.servlets.MultiQueryServlet.handle(MultiQueryServlet.java:470)
        at net.acmecorp.servlets.MultiQueryServlet.doGet(MultiQueryServlet.java:85)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        - locked <0x0000000700dd70d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000076ed40990> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

I’m not really a java guy myself, so I’m not able to see exactly what is wrong here, but it certainly looks like they are all waiting for something...

Comment: It sounds more like an issue with your application than the Tomcat/Jetty in particular.  It could be an object being created and not defreferenced and then the long pauses are the GC trying to re-organise the heap.  When you kill the thread you will release the memory allocated in that thread.

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout, I agree that is seems that way, but we’ve turned on GC logging and can not see any connection between GC and the hangs. Also, as I understand it, GC will cause (sometimes long) pauses, but this process will hang for days if we let it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have database pooling issues, your http threads are all waiting on database resources to free up.  This is a common problem, you either need to increase the number of database connections in your pool so is no longer a problem, or you need to use a QoS service like the QoSFilter in jetty to limit the number of requests that have come in for processes to protect a small database pool.

Now, the reason your database pool has been consumed could be a number of things, you might be leaking them in the application (getting them from pool, using them, and never returning them) or you might just be having too many requests coming in concurrently.  Or an issue in the database pooling libraries themselves, it happens.

Either way, this is not a jetty or tomcat issue, it is a resource contention issue between your application and the database.  Requests are coming into jetty or tomcat, going into servlet lands and then waiting in a servlet or the like for a database connection, simple as that.

Comment: I believe you are right. I didn’t see your reply until now, but this is exactly what we have been working on for the past few hours. We’ve increased GenericObjectPool.maxActive and increased max_connections in MySQL. So far we haven’t had any more hangs, but traffic is slowing down and we won’t know for sure until tomorrow morning. I’ll set this as the accepted answer when we have confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: Nailed it! This may be a common problem, but I have to admit that we spent several days scratching our heads about it. I wish there could have been something in some log file about this. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer.